# Multi Tenant Angular 2 Dart App

Tags: angular, dart, fuelphp

I am developing a multi tenant web application using:

Front - End:  Angular 2 Dart Web Application 
Back - End:   Apache, Fuel-PHP REST API, MySql

Fuel-Php does support multi-tenancy, where you can separate config based on the FuelEnv, in the apache .conf file as 
FuelEnv "client1" in lets say http.conf which routes to

client1.domain.com and loads correct config for the

```
client1 
-db.php 
-config.php  
-upload.php
```

However, when i build the angular 2 dart app and deploy it to the server, it is in the separate document root ...thus has separate apache virtual host configuration... is there any way i can load build dart web apps files from the fuelphp server side to the client, to avoid making a trip to the database to load the application instance configuration?

**Edit #1:**
I tried with success putting the build app files, such as main.dart.js and index.html into the same root as the fuel php rest api; My root route / loads index.php , which in turn includes main.dart.js, but i had to include all other assets with fuelphp Asset:js, Asset:css etc. from project/public/assets... This solution works, but are there any other better solutions out there to deploy angular 2 dart app along with fuelphp rest api services?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problem. 
I gave up messing around with the configs and **.htaccess** file and then, I found a solution but, I'm looking for a better one as well
My solution is

1. Combine the angular project with the Fuel public folder.
2. Copy the angular **index.html** content into the fuel
   **welcome/index.php**.
3. Delete the angular **index.html**
4. Make the fuel **action_404** return the **welcome/index** as well.

This solution made any **http** request be checked by **fuel**, if it exists then good will return a **json** otherwise it's gonna return the **angular app** which will handle the side client routing.

This works for now it may work for you, but I can really use a cleaner solution